# How to decide whether to use deep copy in Java?

Tags: java, deep-copy

I'm new to Java, and get really confused about deep copy.

I think each method that takes some mutable objects as arguments and returns an object that is related to the input should make defensive copy. However, after some coding I find this is very tricky.

For example, I want to choose some objects from a container satisfying some conditions, and returns them as a smaller container:

`List<SomeType> chooseWithSomeCondition(List<SomeType> input)`

But `SomeType` is defined by others, which is not immutable, not clonable, not serializable, neither has any copy constructor. Since Java's `final` cannot help either, I don't know how to make deep copy here.

Is my criteria too strict? Is the code I've read problematic? Are there some other ways to make deep copy? Please share your thoughts, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, the code is problematic, and I'd just do a shallow copy.  In your docs, note that the method is actually "chooseWithSomeConditionAtThisInstant" and tell others NOT to modify the elements of either list, or to do so with care and thought.  (There are use cases where you *want* changes to come through.)

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a type where you cannot use normal copying methods for deep copy (in your case of non-serializable, non-clonable, non-instantiable...), you would need to work around with reflection.

If you think reflection is too slow, or constructors can't be used, then you may want to think about using [`sun.misc.Unsafe`](http://mishadoff.github.io/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/) to instantiate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I read about it and it's very useful.